# Display text when button clicked

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, orchardcms-1.6, knockout-mvc

Creating my first ASP.NET MVC Knockout MVC.

I've added a model setting 3 dates. The controller assigns 3 dates. Then they are displayed on screen using the view:

```
<p>First Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.FirstDate)</p>
<p>Second Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.SecondDate)</p>
<p>Third Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.ThirdDate)</p>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

The @ko.Apply(Model) being the main part which displays the 3 dates.
I am trying to only show the 3 dates when a button is clicked, so iv put the code inside a form and used a button:

```
<form id="displaydates" method="post" >
<p>First Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.FirstDate)</p>
<p>Second Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.SecondDate)</p>
<p>Third Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.ThirdDate)</p>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" @ko.Apply(Model) />
</form>
```

Problem being this no longer displays the dates in the text box, they display them beside the button. To recpa: I would like each date to appear inside the text box when the button is clicked (instead of alongside the button when the page loads - which is what happens atm).

Any ideas?
[image]

Update Tried to add a button, but now the dates dont display at all, even when the button is clicked.

View:

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model KnockOutMVC3Dates.Models.DatesModel       
@{
  var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

<p>First Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.FirstDate)</p>
<p>Second Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.SecondDate)</p>
<p>Third Date: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.ThirdDate)</p>

@ko.Html.Button("Display","Index","Dates",null,null)
```

Dates Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View
                (   new DatesModel
                    {
                        FirstDate = DateTime.Now,

                        SecondDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).AddMonths(1),
                        ThirdDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2).AddMonths(2)
                    }
                );

        }
```

Model:

```
  public class DatesModel
{
    public DateTime FirstDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SecondDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ThirdDate { get; set; }
}
```

Any help or ideas welcome??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="@(ko.Apply(Model))" />
```

I am not especially familiar with Knockout JS but it appears that the return value of `ko.Apply(Model)` is a bunch of JS to populate your fields. If you want to run this on click of your button, you'll want the above. Right now, you're writing out a load of JS into your input tag, which is just breaking.

Comment: thank you for the reply but it is having the same effect. Please see original post for another update. thank you

Answer (score 0):

input tag can be used here like
 
on the onclick event u can give the name of the model also
try this...