# JSon Date Format issue in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

ASP.NET-MVC Knockout MVC.
Screen should show an empty text box. With a button. When the user clicks the button the stored date should display in the text box.

ATM when the screen loads the date is already stored in the text box '0001-01-01T00:00:00'
however when I press the button it changes to: /Date(1366300981661)/.

Anyone have any idea as to why it does this, and how I can get it to only display the date when the button is clicked.

Please see code below:
**Model**

```
public class ClickCounterModel
    {
     public void ShowDates()
        {
            FirstDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public class ClickCounterController : KnockoutController
    {
        public ActionResult ShowDates(ClickCounterModel model)
        {
            model.ShowDates();
            return Json(model);
        }
    }
```

**view**

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model ClickCounter.Models.ClickCounterModel
@{
  var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

<div>Dates: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.FirstDate) </div>
@ko.Html.Button("Show", "ShowDates", "ClickCounter")  

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this really be an edit to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083648/display-text-when-button-clicked/16084511

Comment: @PankajGarg sorry about the delay i'm only getting round to this today. I tried what you suggested: wrapped it in a DOM event and made a ref to the JS file in my view. However I'm still getting the same problem. To test I replaced the code you provided with an 'alert' and it worked fine, so I can only guess there must be some small problem with the code in your answer. Do you have any ideas on what the problem could be? thanks for the reply btw

Comment: The below answer is not working. Did you get a chance to have a look and reply to the sample app I sent to your email?thanks

Comment: @PankajGarg I got the email you sent thanks for the help it worked, great job. On another note I was wondering why the text box contains '0001-01-01T00:00:00' everytime the page loads?? How can i remove it from page loading?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28752/discussion-between-john-and-pankaj-garg)

Comment: Did the below answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting of Date is missing after results are fetched in Json Format.

**JQuery**

```
var MyDate_String_Value = "/Date(1366300981661)/";
var value = new Date
            (
                 parseInt(MyDate_String_Value.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))
            );
var dat = value.getMonth() + 
                         1 + 
                       "/" + 
           value.getDate() + 
                       "/" + 
       value.getFullYear();
```

**[Click here to check result - 4/18/2013](http://jsfiddle.net/8zUED/)**

Comment: thanks for the reply. Where do I paste this though is it in my model?

Comment: In JavaScript File, Wrap this code in DOM ready event. In your view file add the reference of your JavaScript file.

Comment: Please see my replys in the comments section of my Q, thanks Pankaj